# Sounds issue in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, sound, hdmi

I'm trying ubuntu 16.04 and having an issue with the sounds.

After the installation, my desktop PC (Which is with front and back sound input output panels) produced no sounds (Sounds worked fine in Windows 10). After few research I came across with Jack retasking for HDA intel sounds cards.

[image: Jack retasking for HDA intel sounds cards]

It has 2 codec. **Intel Skylake HDMI** and **Realtek ALC 887-VD** . Intel HDMI does not produce any sounds but when I select Realtek and click **Apply now it** works. But after a restart the sounds are not working and I have to run the jack re-tasking to get the sounds working. There is an option  I**nstall boot override** but it does not work.

How can I set the Realtec codec to be the default code?

P.S I'm new to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another method to change the pin configuration is through a shell script when the "Install boot override" funtion does not work. Run `hdajackretask` and select "Remove boot override" then reboot your system.

After reboot, run `hdajackretask` Then To override one of your jacks:

1. Select a codec
2. Click the "Override" checkbox for that pin and select the new
   desired function
3. Click "Apply now"

After you click "Apply now" a shell script is created to make the changes and prompts for super user password to execute. The script is also saved in /tmp which can be copied and later executed with sudo from the command line.

[image]

hdajackretask creates a script, script.sh in /tmp similar to /tmp/hda-jack-retask-QW1EEZ/ for the jack functions you desire:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "0x12 0x90a60140" | tee /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs 2>>/tmp/hda-jack-retask-WFEIEZ/errors.log
echo "0x14 0x90170150" | tee /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs 2>>/tmp/hda-jack-retask-WFEIEZ/errors.log
echo "0x17 0x40000000" | tee /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs 2>>/tmp/hda-jack-retask-WFEIEZ/errors.log
echo "0x18 0x411111f0" | tee /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs 2>>/tmp/hda-jack-retask-WFEIEZ/errors.log
echo "0x19 0x411111f0" | tee /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs 2>>/tmp/hda-jack-retask-WFEIEZ/errors.log
echo "0x1a 0x411111f0" | tee /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs 2>>/tmp/hda-jack-retask-WFEIEZ/errors.log
echo "0x1b 0x411111f0" | tee /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs 2>>/tmp/hda-jack-retask-WFEIEZ/errors.log
echo "0x1d 0x40700001" | tee /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs 2>>/tmp/hda-jack-retask-WFEIEZ/errors.log
echo "0x1e 0x411111f0" | tee /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs 2>>/tmp/hda-jack-retask-WFEIEZ/errors.log
echo "0x21 0x40f000f0" | tee /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs 2>>/tmp/hda-jack-retask-WFEIEZ/errors.log
echo 1 | tee /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/reconfig 2>>/tmp/hda-jack-retask-WFEIEZ/errors.log
```

Copy this script somewhere else on your system (other than /tmp)

```
cd /tmp/hda-jack-retask-QW1EEZ
cp script.sh ~username/speaker.sh
```

Then edit speaker.sh

```
cd ~username
nano speaker.sh
```

Add the line `killall pulseaudio &` at the top of the file. This is necessary because the jack function can not be changed while `pulseaudio` is running. By default `pulseaudio` will respawn. Also change the path to `errors.log` file to `/tmp` or wherever you like:

```
#!/bin/sh
killall pulseaudio &
echo "0x12 0x90a60140" | tee /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs 2>>/tmp/errors.log
echo "0x14 0x90170150" | tee /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs 2>>/tmp/errors.log
echo "0x17 0x40000000" | tee /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs 2>>/tmp/errors.log
echo "0x18 0x411111f0" | tee /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs 2>>/tmp/errors.log
echo "0x19 0x411111f0" | tee /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs 2>>/tmp/errors.log
echo "0x1a 0x411111f0" | tee /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs 2>>/tmp/errors.log
echo "0x1b 0x411111f0" | tee /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs 2>>/tmp/errors.log
echo "0x1d 0x40700001" | tee /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs 2>>/tmp/errors.log
echo "0x1e 0x411111f0" | tee /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs 2>>/tmp/errors.log
echo "0x21 0x40f000f0" | tee /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/user_pin_configs 2>>/tmp/errors.log
echo 1 | tee /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/reconfig 2>>/tmp/errors.log
```

To run the script:

```
sudo ./speaker.sh
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, It did not work.

Comment: even after using pavucontrol?

Comment: yes, In the output Devices it only shows  **Built-ijn Audio Digital stereo (ICE958)** which produced no sounds. but when I apply the jack re-tasking, it works.

Comment: Ill update my answer.

Comment: my speaker.sh file looks like this 
'mv /tmp/hda-jack-retask-B22OGZ/hda-jack-retask.fw /lib/firmware/hda-jack-retask.fw 2>>/tmp/hda-jack-retask-B22OGZ/errors.log 
mv /tmp/hda-jack-retask-B22OGZ/hda-jack-retask.conf /etc/modprobe.d/hda-jack-retask.conf 2>>/tmp/hda-jack-retask-B22OGZ/errors.log. Can I replace them with your code?

Comment: sudo ./speaker.sh 
mv: cannot stat '/tmp/hda-jack-retask-B22OGZ/hda-jack-retask.fw': No such file or directory

Comment: No, my example will not work on your system because the hardware is different.  Please follow the directions exactly as it is written then you can move the script to other directories or do whatever you wish.

Comment: Im sorry but Im bit confused.  In your script.sh file you have echo statements and in mine I have 2 move commands.. `mv /tmp/hda-jack-retask-B22OGZ/hda-jack-retask.fw /lib/firmware/hda-jack-retask.fw 2>>/tmp/hda-jack-retask-B22OGZ/errors.log` and  `mv /tmp/hda-jack-retask-B22OGZ/hda-jack-retask.conf /etc/modprobe.d/hda-jack-retask.conf 2>>/tmp/hda-jack-retask-B22OGZ/errors.log`